# What is PAM and why does AWS enable it by default?

Tags: server, ssh, cron, amazon-ec2, pam

I only want to connect to my EC2 instance using SSH, but my `sshd_config` has `UsePAM yes`. What is this and will I get locked out of my instance if I set it to no?

Also I set a `cronjob` to check if my ZNC bouncer is up and my `/var/log/auth.log` is full of these:

> CRON[5216]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user znc-admin

As you can see there's a `pam_unix` thing which relates back to my first question.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man7/PAM.7.html

Answer (score 9):

Pam is the Pluggable Authentication Modules.

It is a backend for authentication, that handles authentication for applications on a system. As the name says, it's pluggable. You can have multiple *plugs* providing authentication from different sources. A common source is /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow in combination. Others can be LDAP, Kerberos, NIS, or fingerprint readers.

In short, it provides a consistent interface for applications, such as login and ssh, to authenticate against.

It consists of four parts:

1. Accounts - keeping track of usernames.
2. Authentication - checking passwords (or fingerprints.. or ...)
3. Session management - actions to be performed on starting and ending an session, like accounting.
4. Passord updating - updating passwords, and also enforcing password standards.

If we have a look at `man sshd_config` we can read the following:

> UsePAM
> Enables the Pluggable Authentication Module interface.  If set to “yes” this will enable PAM authentication using ChallengeResponseAuthentication and PasswordAuthentication in addition to PAM account and session module processing for all authentication types.
>
> Because PAM challenge-response authentication usually serves an equivalent role to password authentication, you should disable either PasswordAuthentication or ChallengeResponseAuthentication.
>
> If UsePAM is enabled, you will not be able to run sshd(8) as a non-root user.  The default is “no”.

You can set it to no if you do not want to use PAM. On a single standing instance there's no *big* reason to use PAM - you typically only have one authentication source anyway (/etc/passwd / /etc/shadow). On the other hand, there's no big reasons to change either in this environment.

What you see in your log is part of the session modules: it logs users authenticated - in this case because a script was run as this user. This is normal, and not something to worry about, or even care about.

Edit: as the user was brutally aware of - do **not** set it to no unless you either have public key authentication working, or enable other password authentication schemes. With ssh, it's also possible to change config, restart ssh, and try to login **before** logging out from current shell. This way you can revert if you're locket out.

Comment: I changed it to no and restarted ssh.service and now I get "Server refused our key"....

Comment: Strange. Tested on stock vanilla Ubuntu openssh `sshd_config`. Do you still have a shell open? If so change back to PAM and try again.

Comment: No I closed the ssh session after restarting ssh.service. I guess I'm locked out for good?

Comment: Well, you removed PAM, and didn't define any other password authentication methods - and probably didn't have public key set up?

There's ways to recover (set up new machine in same region, connect disk to that instance, edit the config, disk back to old instance and boot old instance), but if you haven't done a lot of configuration it's simpler to start with a new.

Comment: It's fine, I only had a bouncer set up. Anyhow I created a new Ec2 instance and **UsePAM yes** is again the default and I suggest not switching this to no unless you want to be locked out :)